# How to post Key Combination events in Qt like CTRL-L

Tags: qt, qkeyevent, qkeysequence

I know how to post single key event

```
    QKeyEvent *poKeyEvent = new QKeyEvent ( QEvent::KeyPress, Qt::Key_Enter, Qt::NoModifier);
    QCoreApplication::postEvent (this, poKeyEvent);
```

Now I want to post a combination of key events 
for example `QKeySequence(tr("Ctrl+L"));`

Is this a proper way of posting a key sequence events?

```
    // First key event - 'Ctrl'
    QKeyEvent *poFirstKeyEvent = new QKeyEvent ( QEvent::KeyPress, Qt::Key_Control, Qt::NoModifier);
    QCoreApplication::postEvent (this, poFirstKeyEvent);

    // Second key event - 'L'    
    QKeyEvent *poSecondtKeyEvent = new QKeyEvent ( QEvent::KeyPress, Qt::Key_L, Qt::NoModifier);
    QCoreApplication::postEvent (this, poSecondtKeyEvent);
```

Any other way to implement this?

Thanks,

Comment: I think for `CTRL+L` you should right it like: `new QKeyEvent ( QEvent::KeyPress, Qt::Key_L, Qt::ControlModifier);`, i.e. only a single key event should be sent with `L` key and `Ctrl` modifier.

Comment: It's about _key combination_ rather than sequence .. I got it after @vahancho commented.